# Adding target _blank to links after a page has been generated

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a tool that I wrote that takes Word documents (articles) from users, puts them in our website template, then uploads them to our testing web server.

When they are copy and pasting their articles from Word, they would like all links to open in a new window.

Is there a way to accomplish this? I can add a function to the website template from which the articles are being created from.

edit: Your suggestions are great, however, one thing I overlooked was that adding a target blank attribute to ALL a tags will make clicks go to a new window.  Here is one of my pages:

http://www.pachamber.org/newsroom/articles/2012/PA%20Chamber%20unveils%20results%20of%2022nd%20Pennsylvania%20Economic%20Survey.php

Could I limit this to a div?

Comment: How are the links represented when the page has been generated? (For that matter, is the generated page HTML?)

Comment: what is the div `id` you want to limit your selection to?

Comment: Just narrow selection to your `#lipsum` div: `$('#lipsum a').attr('target', '_blank')` - see my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***jQuery***

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#yourDiv a').attr('target', '_blank');
});
```

***Vanilla JS*** (in case this is the only JS on your page, so you don't have to load jQuery)

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById('mydiv');
var links = myDiv.getElementsByTagName('a');

for( var i = 0, len = links.length; i < len; i++ ) {
   links[i].target = "_blank";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So you want to add an attribute of `target` for all links, giving it a value of `_blank`. That's easy:

```
 $("a").attr({target:'_blank'});
```

Comment: Here I am using it as a setter, it applies to all `a`'s. Learn jQuery properly before downvoting immediately as a sign of your `devotion` towards maintaining Stackoverflow standards.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#divWithWordLinks a').attr('target', '_blank');
```

EDIT: see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9twcn/).